# Swiper init could not get element?

Tags: swiper.js

I want to get the element at initialization, but what I got in the first place is undefined

Below is my code

**html**

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>
```

**javascript**

```
 window.onload = () => {
        new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
            on: {
                init() {
                    console.log('Init complete?')
                    console.log(this.navigation.nextEl) //undefined

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log(this.navigation.nextEl);//object
                    }, 10)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain that further? What kind of "element" would you like to "get" at which "initialization"?

Comment: I want to use 'this.navigation.nextEl' in the init() to get '.swiper-button-next', but what I get is undefined.